Can balloon frame subfloor strapping safely be removed, temporarily, for the purpose of sistering new joists in order to level a 2nd story floor?
I have a house built in 1940, and I have gutted a second-story room, removed all of the lath and plaster, ran new electrical wiring and installed new batted insulation.
The floor is very out of level, and the joists get lower as I move from one to the next (The right side joists get lower in the photo, the left side is going up).  They are level down their length, but as they are mounted side to side, one is slightly lower than the one before it, stepping down a bit with each one.
My county inspector said not to remove the strapping you can see in the photo below becuase it is part of the structure - he didn't clarify if he meant "at all" or simply not to remove it permanently.  The subfloor was tongue and groove deck board that I have already removed, which was installed on top of the strapping.
If I can safely remove the strapping and replace it with new wood, that would give me a chance to sister the old joists and level the floor that way.  If I cannot remove the strapping to sister the joists, then I would have a much more difficult solution to find.
There are another 3 layers of drywall glued to the bottom of that lath and plaster on the ceiling below, so these joists are holding a lot of weight simply from the former owners taking shortcuts when remodeling the ceilings in the past instead of removing the old drywall and installing new material on the bottom of the joists.
How should this floor-leveling be done?  Is all of that weight from the multiple layers of material on the ceiling below a significant concern?


I have a feeling that some/a few rows at a time might be removed, but removing all together for a short time might be bad.  It might be stopping the house from racking/shifting side to side.  The inspector knows a lot more than I do.
